# Creating a userscript to change the stylesheet of a website upon clicking between two buttons

Tags: javascript, html, css, userscripts

Ok so I've compiled this code after looking around, to at least make sure that in principle, changing from one css source to another should work.
The code is this:

Main page

```
  <html><head><link rel="Stylesheet" href=""  type="text/css" 

id="style"/>
    <script 

src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jque

ry.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('button').click(function () {
                var txt = $(this).html();
                if(txt=='Night Mode')
                    {

                $('link#style').attr('href', 'https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/izi0tg7r5foax78/two.css');
                return false;
                     }
                 else if (txt == 'Day Mode') {
                  $('link#style').attr('href', 'https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/gf7te23q27tht3w/one.css');
                  return false;               }

            });

        });

    </script>
<title>WOT</title><head>
<body>

LOL
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <h1>My Website</h1>
    <br />
    <button>Night Mode</button>
    <button>Day Mode</button>
    </div>
    </form>


</body>
```

And CSS One and two just have the same line in it for test purposes, with only the color being the difference.

```
body {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

And my question is:
How do I compile this code, into a usescript that will change the css link source, when clicking one of the two buttons that will be sitting on the page I have in mind.

Thank you for your help/time :)

Comment: Are you expecting the CSS to already exist on the site in question? That is, could you really use `$('link#style').attr('href', 'one.css');`?

Comment: No, the css link would be hosted externally, so a full url would be used.

Comment: How do you want to use this? Are you making a browser plugin or will you be using a third party extension to inject this?

Comment: If you can link to it directly, it should be trivial - just put everything inside the `<script>` into the userscript text, require jQuery, and change the CSS links. (But there's no need for jQuery for this, you might consider using plain Javascript instead)

Comment: @Jerodev A userscript implies a userscript manager such as Tampermonkey or Greasemonkey.

Comment: @Jerodev As an extension, like a theme changer for google, that would use multiple stylesheets.

Comment: @CertainPerformance The css would be targeting pre-existing css.

Comment: A userscript runs on a page you do not control.  Is that what you are trying to do here, or do you have a server hosting this page yourself?  If the former, do you have to add these buttons to the page?

Comment: A user script that runs on a page I do not control. I'll use google for example. So the goal is to make a userscript that is a theme/color changer for the website it runs on. That will have at least 2 buttons, that when clicked, will change the appearance of the page, using the external css files that they are linked to.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps you. Written a userscript to change theme in pure Javascript. (Just written css based on StackOverFlow).

The script adds a dropdown at the top right corner of all pages. On selecting a theme, the same is updated in the page. Save it in Tampermonkey and reload this page.

Giving css for commonly used tags/ids/classes like `body`, `div`, `.container`, `.content`, `.nav-bar`, `.sidebar`, might make the following to work in multiple sites.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         StackOverFlow
// @namespace    VigeshRaja_UserScripts
// @version      0.1
// @description  Testing
// @author       Vignesh Raja
// @match        http*://*/*
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
    'use strict';
    var selectelem = `<div class="themecolor">
                        <select id="themecolor" onchange="changeTheme()">
                            <option value="default">Default</option>
                            <option value="sunny">Sunny</option>
                            <option value="night">Night</option>
                            <option value="rosy">Rosy</option>
                        </select>
                      </div>`;
    var basestyle = ".themecolor{position: fixed; top: 0; right: 0; z-index: 100000000; padding: 10px; background: #e43939;} body{background: $bodycolor$; color: $bodyfontcolor$;}#content{background-color: $contentcolor$;}";
    var modes = {default: {bodycolor:"", bodyfontcolor: "", contentcolor:""},
                sunny : {bodycolor:"f8d767", bodyfontcolor: "ffffff", contentcolor:"d4bb82"},
                night : {bodycolor:"969590", bodyfontcolor: "ffffff", contentcolor:"585753"},
                 rosy : {bodycolor:"f59bda", bodyfontcolor: "ffffff", contentcolor:"f59bda"}};

    function addStyle(style)
    {
        var headelem = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
        var styleelem = document.createElement("style");
        styleelem.setAttribute("id","customtheme");
        styleelem.type="text/css";
        styleelem.appendChild(document.createTextNode(style));
        headelem.appendChild(styleelem);
    }

    window.changeTheme = function(){
        var style = basestyle;
        var theme = document.getElementById("themecolor").value;
        for(var colortype of Object.keys(modes[theme]))
        {
            style = style.replace("$"+colortype+"$", "#"+modes[theme][colortype]);
        }

        var customtheme = document.getElementById("customtheme");
        if(customtheme)
        {
            customtheme.remove();
        }
        addStyle(style);
    }

    document.body.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend",selectelem);
    addStyle(basestyle);
})();
```